# When do creatures start receiving additional attacks while under Freezing Cloud?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, wizard

The effect part of the Freezing Cloud spell description reads (PHB, p. 160):

> Effect: The cloud lasts until the end of your next turn. Any
>   creature that enters the cloud or starts its turn there is
>   subject to another attack. You can dismiss the cloud as a
>   minor action.

Do I understand correctly that whatever creature was caught in the blast when it was cast *will not* receive additional attacks until that creature's turn has started?  And what does "attack" mean here?  Additional attack from that spell, or that whoever attacks that creature may attack it twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You get to repeat Freezing Cloud's attack against creatures that enter the cloud or start their turn there.**

Freezing Cloud has an attack line. When you use the power, you make that attack and resolve its hit effects on any targets you hit.

Freezing Cloud also creates a zone. Until the end of your next turn, any time a creature starts its turn in the zone or enters the zone (the entering has probably been errata-ed to only happen once per turn), you can repeat Freezing Cloud's attack and (if you hit) hit lines against *that creature*.

The zone doesn't care whether the creature was targeted by the initial attack. If another effect slides a creature into the zone before its turn, you can make Freezing Cloud's attack against that creature when it starts its turn in the zone, even though it wasn't one of the original targets. If another effect slides a creature out of the zone before its turn, you won't get to make Freezing Cloud's attack against it when it starts its turn outside the zone, even though it was one of the original targets.

Freezing Cloud does not allow any additional attacks other than Freezing Cloud's attack line.